# SD card turns slow after split partitions and format

Tags: partitioning, gparted, sd-card

It's a class 10 SD card, and the speed is normal (about 10MB/s write) before I use GParted to split it into 2 partitions and format them as EXT4.

But then the speed is only about 1.5MB/s write after that...

After I delete the partitions and format it as FAT32, it seems to turns to normal, but still slower, at about 8-9MB/s write.

It's because I can't partition a micro-SD card or I can't use EXT4 on it? Or it needs specific cluster size?

I've googled for a while, I've found some say should format SD cards as FAT32, and some say the cluster size should be 64K, some say the cluster size should be 32K.

I'm confusing now.

Comment: Also, I tested in Android phone with a SD card testing App, it said the write speed is 14 to 15MB/s, which is much faster than the write speed seen in my Ubuntu machine.